# Frequency of an Attribute

Tags: python, pandas

Using Python and Pandas: For a given data set, how do you find the number of a specific attribute? For example I have 16 columns of data with over 600 rows. I want to find how many of attribute "g" is in column A5. I have attached the code I found, but it does not give the correct value or use a specific column.

```
df = df['g'].value_counts().reset_index()
df.rows = ['g', 'count']
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Subset `value_counts()`.

```
df['g'].value_counts()['a']
```